# Batch file to execute redis commands

Tags: batch-file, redis

I am trying to write below commands in batch file.

```
cd C:\Redis
redis-cli 
select 6
```

file name is "xxx.bat"

It should connects to local redis instance and select database 6.

but it stops at second command "redis-cli". and does not even write second command "select 6"
on command prompt.
I mean i connects to server , but does not write next command.

I think i do not know something about executing commands in batch file. 
I can run these commands outside of batch file without any problem.
Can somebody please spot the problem.

Regards

Comment: try with `call redis-cli`.Is `redis-cli` a bat file?

Answer (score 6):

`CMD` does not pass the commands to the `redis-cli`. 
You can test it with `quit` from the `redis-cli`, you will see a a `CMD` error for the `select 6` command.

You should put all of your commands (without connecting with redis-cli) in a text file e.g `test.txt` and pass it all to to `redis-cli`. i.e:

`type test.txt | redis-cli -x`

p.s. there's no need to specify `.exe` or any other extension that is in you %pathext% variable, but it makes your scripts more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cmd /c "redis-cli select 6" >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to specify exe with the command.
redis-cli.exe select 6

Answer (score 0):

With my redis 2.4.6 on windows you can pass the command as an argument to the redis-cli executable.  Here is my windows batch file:

```
SET REDIS_PATH=E:\Program Files\Redis

"%REDIS_PATH%\redis-cli" select 6
```

Of course you would change the redis path variable to wherever you have copied / installed Redis to.

Here is the output from running the windows batch file:

[image]