# run multiple command in single powershell context

Tags: azure, powershell, redis

I was trying to run multiple commands one after another and all should run in same context, but its not working. Created ps1 file and try to run below commands

1. cd 'C:\Redis-x64-3.0.504'
2. .\redis-cli.exe -p 6380 -a "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
3. keys *
4. flushall

After running #2, #3 & #4 should run in same context, but its running on current context and throwing error. If i run these script in single powershell manually then it worked.

I tried to run these commands using '|' and '&' but not worked.
Also tried to rung as below:
Invoke-Expression '.\redis-cli.exe -p 6380 -a "xxxxxxxxxxx" | keys *'. But this also not worked.

Comment: tried : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342715/batch-file-to-execute-redis-commands
and this worked for me: type test.txt | redis-cli -x

Answer (score 0):

use a pipe:

```
cd 'C:\redis-x64-3.0.504'
echo keys * flushall | .\redis-cli.exe -p 6380 -a "xxxxxx"
```

redis-cli and powersheell commands are not the same. make sure to note the diff.

looks like flushall will delete all keys from your databases...is that what you want to do here?

**Update**

try making the reds command a var like so:

```
$redisCommands = "SELECT $redisDBIndex`r`n FLUSHDB`r`n QUIT`r`n"
$redisCommands | .\nc $redisServer 6380
```

you will need to make sure Netcat is added too

Comment: Tried using pipe but not worked. Yes, want to clear/flush all keys after connecting Azure Redis using powershell commands. All are working when triggered as single command but not working in single ps script.